# esp32: isolate gpio activities from runtime

Tags: esp32, multitasking, led

i'm new with esp32 wroom. I'm trying to develop a system to drive a ws2812 led strip. The system needs to be controlled by a ble android app. For this reason i created a project from bluedroid gatt server demo in eclipse.
The ws2812 strips needs 3 bytes (RGB) for every led and every bit is discriminated bye the dutycycle of a square wave signal with period of about 1,25us.
i did a test writing code that write an out pin port with 1 and 0 with inside a while(true) loop. In this manner i reach the min period of about 1us. For this reason i choose to create a simple serial flow with a brutal way like this:

```
void ledStrip_send_bit0()
{
    gpio_set_level(LED_STRIP_SIGNAL_OUT_GPIO, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++);
    gpio_set_level(LED_STRIP_SIGNAL_OUT_GPIO, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++);
}

void ledStrip_send_bit1()
{
    gpio_set_level(LED_STRIP_SIGNAL_OUT_GPIO, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++);
    gpio_set_level(LED_STRIP_SIGNAL_OUT_GPIO, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++);
}
```

probably this is a bad way but this method works fine.
The problem detected is relate to the interrupts of the system sure enough any interrupt creates a margin of error in the timing of the control signal of led strip.
for this reason many leds works in a random way.
To write 128 leds the esp32 takes about 4ms so using taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS(); befor port writing and taskENABLE_INTERRUPTS(); after it, the led strips is not affected by any random lighting.
In this way i'm also able to send a ble message to control the lights but i think that this is a bad way and i want to improve the entire system.

I tryed to use a task with other core to isolate the activities hoping uselessly to solve the problem.

So my question is:

- can i solve increasing the cpu speed clock? how to do it?
- There is a way to create a signal not affected by any cpu activities like interrups??

Thanks
Marco

Comment: No. Yes. Is there a reason not to just use [FastLED](http://fastled.io) or a similar library? It properly solves the problems you're trying to solve.

Comment: "I'm trying to develop a system to drive a ws2812 led strip", If you are using esp-idf, there is actually a built-in [led_strip](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/peripherals/rmt/led_strip) library for controlling ws2812 as a RMT peripheral. You don't need to re-invent the wheel or using an external library like FastLED.

Comment: API documentation can be found [here](https://esp-idf-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/groups/led_strip.html).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I changed the method with RMT peripheral. (i not used the library so i re-invented the wheel however i seen how rmt works and i appreciated it).
This was a good idea but the ble interrupts make some interference with rmt tx signal. In any case in solved the problem through the configuration: in my eclipse i opened sdkconfig and i set the ble with core1 and i increase the cpu speed to 240MHz. Now it seems works correctly :)